# PPTP VPN fails to work after waking from sleep

Tags: macos, mac, osx-snow-leopard, pptp

If I forget to disconnect the PPTP VPN before closing the lid on my Mac, annoying things happen when I open the lid (wake it from sleep).

At best, network traffic stops until I disconnect the VPN. If I wait some minutes, it will disconnect itself. Or, if it's in a particularly annoying mood, the entire menu bar (all icons) will show a busy spinner for quite a while, preventing me from doing anything.

Anyone know a recipe to make PPTP disconnect as part of suspend to avoid all this?

Mac OS X 10.6.4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [sleepwatcher](http://www.bernhard-baehr.de/) to run a custom script.

Edit:
 
bmargulies: "Do you happen to know would I disconnect the VPN from a command line?"

I haven't done this (disconnect via the command line) but here's a page I found with some [sample scripts](http://blog.heatery.com/2008/06/how-to-connect-or-disconnect-pptp-vpn.html) for establishing and disconnecting VPN connections.  I'd start there.

Comment: Do you happen to know would I disconnect the VPN from a command line?